# Any plot graph library for Gtkmm-3.0?

Tags: plot, gtkmm

I am working on gui using Gtkmm-3.0? Now that I want to plot simple `2D-graph`. I did google and found [plotmm](http://plotmm.sourceforge.net/index.html). It looks like what I want. But in the installation notes, they say Gtkmm-2.0 is required. I could not find any plotting graph library for `Gtkmm-3.0`. Could anyone please recommend such library?